# PowerAutomate ForEach user loop

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, power-automate

I have an automate-admin account (as a global admin) that runs my flows.

Some graph API calls run in the context of the user, and return results related to the user calling (i.e. functions that list my planner tasks).

Is it possible for the automate-admin to run as a user so that when calling the graph API it would return the user info?

Pseudo code is below:

```
ForEach (user in users)
   Context = SwitchUserContext(user)
   Context.Switch()
   // Any calls here are as if user is calling API
   ... Call API ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can click on the three dots: ...
From that screen, you can choose if it's the user connection or your admin connection.